# Powershell: match operator returns true but $matches is null

Tags: regex, powershell

I am working with a regex to match file contents:

```
> (get-content $_) -match $somePattern
the line of text that matches the pattern
```

this returns true, a match, however my $matches variable remains null.

```
> $matches -eq $null
True
```

Shouldn't $matches have the match groups in it?

Comment: Show an example with actual data - your regex and the text that matched.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Strictly speaking `string -match ...` and `collection -match ...` are two different operators.
The first gets a Boolean value and fills `$matches`.
The second gets each collection item that matches a pattern and apparently does not fill `$matches`.

Your example should work as you expect if the file contains a single line (the first operator works).
If a file contains 2+ lines then the second operator is used and `$matches` is not set.

The same is true for other Boolean operators applied to a collection.
That is `collection -op ...` returns items where `item -op ...` is true.

Examples:

```
1..10 -gt 5 # 6 7 8 9 10
'apple', 'banana', 'orange' -match 'e' # apple, orange
```

Boolean operators applied to collections are handy if used properly.
But they may be confusing as well and lead to easy to make mistakes:

```
$object = @(1, $null, 2, $null)

# "not safe" comparison with $null, perhaps a mistake
if ($object -eq $null) {
    '-eq gets @($null, $null) which is evaluated to $true by if!'
}

# safe comparison with $null
if ($null -eq $object) {
    'this is not called'
}
```

Another example with `-match` and `-notmatch` may look confusing:

```
$object = 'apple', 'banana', 'orange'

if ($object -match 'e') {
    'this is called'
}

if ($object -notmatch 'e') {
    'this is also called, because "banana" is evaluated to $true by if!'
}
```

Comment: Yup, this is exactly it. My get-content returns an array and the last line doesn't match, causing $matches to empty out.

Comment: Very thorough answer, @Roman! For another perspective (and with an Alice in Wonderland twist!) interested readers might also take a look at my article [Harnessing PowerShell's String Comparison and List-Filtering Features](http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/harnessing-powershells-string-comparison-and-list-filtering-features/) published on Simple-Talk.com. Attached to the article is a wallchart illustrating the `-match` operator (and variants) in both scalar and array context, along with many other operators.

Comment: Quick note, try using a `foreach..` to cycle through the members of an array (maybe create a conditional to check `$obj.gettype()`), then you can use `-match` as you probably want... worth noting this strategy to find specific matches http://stackoverflow.com/a/3520237/843000

Comment: `Get-Clipboard` = collection; `Get-Clipboard -Raw` = string. Learned the hard way....

Comment: `Get-Content` also has `-Raw` switch. This is definitely the ugly/quirky side of PowerShell. But then you have to match with `(?m)` modifier, because now its a string with newlines. And then it matches only 1 result.

Comment: What you can do is `gc $_ | sls -Pattern $somePattern -AllMatches` which gives you collection of `MatchInfo` objects

Answer (score 13):

I had the same problem, and the exact lines were working from the Powershell command prompt but not from Powershell ISE or a normal command prompt. If you don' want to cycle through all the lines of the file one by one using foreach, you can simply convert that to a string like this and it should work then:

```
if([string](Get-Content -path $filePath) -match $pattern)
{
   $matches[1]
}
```