# -match succeeds but doesn't update $matches

Tags: regex, powershell

I've written a script to invoke an external command and capture a part of its output using a regular expression. Here is an example (not real-world) script to demonstrate how I'm doing this:

```
$output = clip
if ($output -imatch 'usage')
{
    Write-Output $matches[0]
}
```

If I run `clip` at the command prompt, its output looks like this:

> INFO: Type "CLIP /?" for usage.

In the above code, the match is successful, but `$matches` isn't set. If I set `$output` using a different method such as the following, the problem goes away:

```
$output = 'INFO: Type "CLIP /?" for usage.'
```

Why is `$matches` not set when I invoke the command? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you run `clip.exe` without parameters, the result is:

```
PS > clip

Infos : Entrez "CLIP /?" pour afficher la syntaxe.
```

There are two lines produced:

1. A carriage return / line feed (empty)
2. A second line with text

So when you write `$output = clip`, you're assigning an array to `$output`. `$output[0]` is the empty line and `$output[1]` is the text line. The `Out-String` cmdlet removes the unnecessary CR/LF.

You can try something like this:

```
clip | where {$_ -imatch 'syntaxe'} | % {$matches}
```

---

Edited

As far as I understand, the reason why `$matches` is not populated is the input to `-imatch` is an array. As you can read in [about_comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx):

> "**When the input is scalar**, it [`-match` operator] populates the `$Matches` automatic variable.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer still doesn't explain why `$matches` wasn't set, though.

Comment: Of course it explains ! have a look to [man about_comparison_Operators](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) "When the input **is scalar**, it populates the $Matches automatic variable.

Comment: Thanks. If you update your answer to explain this, I'll probably accept it.

Comment: Thanks! I'm about to edit your answer to make it clearer, and then I think I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1):

I checked the type of `$output` and discovered that it seemed to be an array instead of a string. I resolved this by changing the first line in the above example to:

```
$output = clip | Out-String
```

I'm new to PowerShell, so an explanation is welcome.

Comment: You can find the explanation at the similar Q & A: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8651905/323582