# PowerShell Issues with getting string from file

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-lookarounds, lookbehind

#### Problem

I am working on an automated version control script in powershell and I hit a snag where I am trying pull a line of text from an AssemblyInfo.cs file. However, I can't seem to get it to work as expected despite all my efforts.

After many trial and errors to achieve the results intended, I have come to find the following to get close to what I'm trying to achieve:

```
# Constants
$Assembly = Get-Item "C:\generalfilepath\*\Assembly.cs"
$regex = '(?<!\/\/ \[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(")(?<=\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\(")[^"]*'

$CurrentVersion = GC $Assembly
$CurrentVersion = $CurrentVersion -match $regex

Write-Host "CurrentVersion = $CurrentVersion
```

I am expecting to see: `CurrentVersion = 1.0.0.0` or something similar, but what I get is: `CurrentVersion = [assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]`

I have been searching all over for examples on how to properly utilize regex with PowerShell, but I have not really found anything that contains more than the regex itself... As such, I was hoping someone here could assist me in either steering me in the right direction or point out what I am doing wrong.

#### Question

Despite the use of the regex filter, I'm getting the entire line instead of just the value I want. How do I ensure the variable stores ONLY the target value using the lookbehind and lookahead regex filters?

Comment: `Get-Content` returns an array of lines, `-match` on an array of lines filters it for the lines which match the regex. It's not clear if you're expecting one file, since you use a wildcard in the path, but however you do it, you need to reference `$Matches` after using `-match`  to get the match details. Probably `Get-Content -Raw` to get a single string, and `-match` and then `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
C:\> ([string] (Get-Content \AssemblyInfo.cs)) -match 'AssemblyVersion\("([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}){1}"\)'
True
```

Afterwards the result shall be store in `$Matches[1]`

```
C:\> $Matches[1]
6.589.0.123
```

Be aware to cast the results of `Get-Content` to `[string]` otherwise `$Matches` will be `$null`. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8651905/powershell-match-operator-returns-true-but-matches-is-null) for a complete description.

If you want to use a more "greedy" regex like `^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}){1}"\)` which also includes a check (`^\[assembly:`) that the string starts with `[assembly` you've to walk through the `[string[]]` array `Get-Content` returns:

```
> gc .\AssemblyInfo.cs | % { $_ -match '^\[assembly: AssemblyVersion\("([0-9]+(\.([0-9]+|\*)){1,3}){1}"\)' }

> $Matches[1]
6.589.0.*
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you. This cleared things up greatly. I was totally confused and was frustrated because I felt like a hamster on a wheel, going nowhere fast. Thank you for the explanation and the link to further information.