# PowerCli substring extraction

Tags: powershell, grep, substring, string-matching, powercli

I need to read the Ethernet adapter name from a PowerCli string so I can, through a script, and without user interaction, use it to change the ip address on a windows machine.

Here is how the powerCli string, from where I'm going to read the substring, will look:

```
C:\> $myIpInfoString
```

ScriptOutput

---

|

|  Windows IP Configuration
|
|

|  Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 6:
|

|     Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :

|     Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 255.255.255.255

|     Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.255

|     Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

### |

how can I end up with another string variable that includes something like:

```
C:\>$myGoalString
Local Area Connection 6
```

The reason why this is important is because the number 6 changes from one machine to the other and can be, for example, "Local Area Connection 15".

Comment: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988880/extricate-substring-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Select-String`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx):

```
$myGoalString = $myIpInfoStrong |
                  Select-String '^[\s\S]*?Ethernet adapter (.*?):' |
                  select -Expand Matches | select -Expand Groups |
                  select -Last 1 Value
```

With PowerShell v3 or newer you can simplify that a little, like this:

```
$myGoalString = $myIpInfoStrong |
                  Select-String '^[\s\S]*?Ethernet adapter (.*?):' |
                  % { $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value }
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but for some reason it didn't work. I'm using the 32 bit powerCli environment, but I'm assuming that it should work with it okay.

Comment: I found an answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988880/extricate-substring-using-powershell

Comment: @user3780375 Did you try the first solution? How exactly did it "not work". Do you have PowerShell v3 or newer installed?

Comment: Yes, of course I did! And I'm using PowerCli 5.5 release 1. The $myGoalString was empty after each call of the solution you provided.

Comment: @user3780375: I just double-checked with PowerCLI 5.5 Release 1 on Win7, and the code works exactly as it should. If it doesn't work for you then your input data is not what you claim it is.