# How can I bulk rename file after specific words?

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, batch-rename

For example

> test-123-abc.mp4
>   test-456-def.mp4

I want to remove all after `_` or `-`. So the result should be:

> 123.mp4
>   456.mp4

Is it possible to use Windows cmd or a batch file, PowerShell to rename?

Comment: PowerShell has a replace method which you can use to replace 
 string/characters/rename files....https://ss64.com/ps/replace.html

Comment: read this...https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/11/22/use-powershell-to-rename-files-in-bulk/

Comment: Let's me take a look :) Thanks !

Comment: When i try to replace its still the same, the result is test123abc.mp4 :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extricate a substring using PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988880/extricate-a-substring-using-powershell)

Comment: @Manu this is a list of my files,can you show me how to do it ? https://i.imgur.com/0X3HWcf.png

Comment: `for %F in ("*-*-*.mp4") do for /F "tokens=2 delims=-" %E in ("%~nF") do ren "%~F" "%~E.%~xF"` or `for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=-" %E in ('dir /B "*-*-*.mp4"') do ren "%E-%F-%G" "%F%~xG"` (double the `%`-signs in a batch file)

Comment: @Enuma : if you want to remove all after "-" or "_", it means you just want to keep the first word and your example shows that you want the word in the middle. Please be more specific.

Comment: Yeah Manu,did you take a look at my picture in my cmt above?

Comment: Looking at those files in your off site image, should your question not be, how to remove everything from and including the last dash, **`-`**, in my file names?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all the file name are in the same format. 
This is just an example, you have to write the script yourself. If you are facing any issue, post the script.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Videos -File | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace "Combo.*","Combo.mp4" }
```

Ex.

```
'test-123-abc.mp4' -replace '.*-(.*)-.*(\..*)','$1$2'
123.mp4
'test-456-def.mp4' -replace '.*-(.*)-.*(\..*)','$1$2'
456.mp4

'TRG-21-Aries Combo-JM5rowKV9TU.mp4' -replace 'Combo.*','Combo.mp4'
TRG-21-Aries Combo.mp4
```

Comment: You should wait for her to be clearer as the result she wants in the question is not corresponding to `"I want to remove all after "_" or "-"`. The result should be `test.mp4` for both files...

Comment: posted examples on how to use replace

Comment: @VincentK Please take a look at my picture https://i.imgur.com/0X3HWcf.png the name is the youtube_id so i want to remove it and only keep the name of the video !

Comment: One of the file name is "TRG-21-Aries Combo-JM5rowKV9TU.mp4" so i want it to be this name "TRG-21-Aries Combo.mp4"

Comment: @VincentK Thank you,but it still change name of 1 file,i want all the file in the folder,is that possible ? because "'TRG-21-Aries Combo-JM5rowKV9TU.mp4' -replace" i have to input the name of the file..

Comment: yes it is possible...I posted an example... you have to try it yourself

Comment: Yeah,but for every files,i have to input the file name,i want all the file of 1 folder..its not just "TRG-21-Aries Combo-JM5rowKV9TU.mp4" they have different name :(

Comment: Updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the rename to occur on all .mp4 files in the directory. If so, this might work. When you are satisfied that the files will be correctly renamed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the Move-Item command.

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter *.mp4 |
    ForEach-Object {
        $newname = $_.Name -replace '(.*)[-_].*(\..*)','$1$2'
        Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName $newname -WhatIf
    }
```